# Cisco Show mac address table

Tags: cisco

How long will a MAC address stay in the mac-address-table on a Cisco switch (let's say a 3750)? I'm not talking about the ARP table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default time-out is 5 minutes.  This is for the dynamically learned addresses.